# Gradle can't find com.google.protobuf

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile a project with protobuf using gradle. However, I'm getting the following errors in the protobuf generated java file:

[image]

Here's the build.gradle file:

```
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'


// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.7'
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Any hint of what's missing?

Comment: I don't think `protobuf-gradle-plugin` should be part of your applications dependencies. Rather it's a gradle plugin that goes at the top gradle file, and you'll need to apply it

Answer (score 0):

For me updating this line

> artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.18.0"

to have the same version number as this line fixed the problem.

> implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0"

```
dependencies {
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.18.0"
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.18.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```